# Extracting phrases from 2-grams

Tags: python, algorithm, information-retrieval

```
The Foo Fighters performed at... 
(The Foo) (Foo Fighters) (Fighters performed) (performed at)...
```

I have a list of 2-grams derived concatenated from many sentences. I want to extract phrases of two and three words (`The Foo Fighters`, `Bill Gates`) from the entire list. But I want to **reject longer phrases** (`to cancel this newsletter, please click...`).

**Edit:** That is, I want to extract those phrases that are **likely to be entities** such as nouns.

What is a good approach for this?

---

The simplest approach I came up with is to consider only 2-word phrases and filtering stop words. But it wont take in `The Foo Fighters`. I also briefly considered TF-IDF to demote phrases that are too common.

Comment: You're saying you want *common* 2- and 3-grams? (In other words, what distinguishes `Bill Gates` or `The Foo Fighters` from other 2-grams and 3-grams?)

Comment: Yes and thats the simplest way, I guess. But I also want to reject them if they are part of repeated sentences (or sentence fragments).

Comment: So you want common 2/3-grams that appear in different contexts each time? (Also- are all the n-grams you want proper nouns, so that they'll be capitalized?)

Comment: Yes, if it makes them **likely** that they are entities (like proper/common nouns). And they may not be capitalized as they are casual communication like Email is.

Comment: It seeems clear that that should be weighted in your approach, though. (You can also consider non-capitalized frequency, and just weight it less).

Answer (score 1):

For a Uni. project I had to do something very similar to what you are describing.

We tried the following approaches:

1. Get the idf value for each 2-gram (we used Bing Developer API, although not exact, it can evaluate if the phrase has 10 hits or 10,000,000 hits). Of course a normalization must be made (It worth nothing having a lot of hits on a 2-gram made of very common words).
2. Wikipedia - We tried searching for the phrase in wikipedia (search if there is an article for it, or an article that the phrase is a substring of it), and took phrases that has a good match
3. Some another advanced - case specific algorithm, described by Ran El-Yaniv as *Co-Occuring Ranking* in an article.

From the 3 above, the wikipedia based algorithm achieved the best performance by a great margin (with p_value < 0.05, don't remember how much exactly)

- We also wanted to implement another algorithm based on the [google n-grams dataset](http://books.google.com/ngrams/datasets), but did not have the time for it unfortunately.

---

How we did it exactly was:

- Each algorithm (denoted as scorer) gave a score to each 2-gram.
- Then we ran a second algorithm (filter) that chose the "best" 2-grams. We tried a simple precentage algrotihm (for example: "get the top 7%"), fixed score (for example: "above 0.5"), and a dynamic algorithm, that looked for a big margin in the scores, and used it to decide how many 2-grams to take.

For wikipedia ranker - the fixed and dynamic scored similar results, for the others - the dynamic was the best we tried.